# How do I enable Copy/Paste/Select all menu in MaterialEditorRenderer Editor

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Forms to render an Editor that allows for multi-line text. However, when I long press in the Editor box when it already has more than 1 line of text, the menu is not showing up to select/cut/copy the text. How do I enable this menu? It works if it's a single line of text.

I have already set this to true, so it should work but doesn't work. `Control.EditText.SetTextIsSelectable`

This is the code I have in the Android Project.

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
    
    namespace MyProject.Droid.MRenderers
    {
        public class CustomEditorRenderer : MaterialEditorRenderer
        {
            public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }
    
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                Control?.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    
                if (Control != null)
                {
                        //This is the HeightRequest 
                        var ElementHeightRequest = Element.HeightRequest;
                        //Convert it to Pixels
                        var EditTextHeight= ConvertToPixels(ElementHeightRequest);
                        //Set the Control's EditText height 
                        Control.EditText.SetHeight(200);
                        Control.EditText.SetTextIsSelectable(true);                
                    Control.EditText.Background = null;
                    Control.EditText.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `AutoSize` property instead of `SetHeight` in renderer.

Custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Control.Background = null;
        Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
       
    }

}
}
```

Xaml:

```
        <local:CustomEditor AutoSize="TextChanges" Text="I am using Xamarin Forms to render an Editor that allows for multi-line text. However, when I long press in the Editor box when it already has more than 1 line of text, the menu is not showing up to select/cut/copy the text. How do I enable this menu? It works if it's a single line of text. I have already set this to true, so it should work but doesn't work."></local:CustomEditor>
```

You could check the output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKwaV.jpg

**Updated:**

I do no changes for the renderer. It could show the Copy/Paste/Select menu in MaterialEditorRenderer Editor.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMaterialEditor), 
typeof(CustomMaterialEditorRenderer))]
namespace Test3.Droid
{
public class CustomMaterialEditorRenderer : MaterialEditorRenderer
{
    public CustomMaterialEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Control.Background = null;
        Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //Control.DispatchSetSelected(true);               
        //Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        //Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);

    }      
}
 }
```

Xaml:

```
   <local:CustomMaterialEditor
            AutoSize="TextChanges"
            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
            Text="I am using Xamarin Forms to render an Editor that allows for multi-line text. However, when I long press in the Editor box when it already has more than 1 line of text, the menu is not showing up to select/cut/copy the text. How do I enable this menu? It works if it's a single line of text. I have already set this to true, so it should work but doesn't work." />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help but this didn't work. I am using MaterialEditorRenderer not EditorRenderer. I also need to set the height that way.

Comment: Do you have any specifical features with `MaterialEditorRenderer`? If not, you could try to use the `EditorRenderer`.

Comment: Yes, MaterialEditorRenderer has special features I want to use not EditorRenderer. Thanks

Comment: I would check the `MaterialEditorRenderer ` and feedback ASAP.

Comment: @user1179083 I have updated my reply. I do no changes for the editor in renderer. The Copy/Paste/Select menu still shows. Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you try it on an actual device? If so, is it a Samsung device? This isn't working on a Samsung Tab A and a Samsung XCover pro devices.

Comment: I do not have the Samsung Tab A and a Samsung XCover pro devices to test. I tested on MI NOTE. It works. You could check the gif. https://imgur.com/t2i2Xec Maybe it cause by the device version.